# Join two table and sum count issue

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have three tables

table 1

```
c_id    c_name         status    p_id         created_at
1       john            1         79        2016-04-13 10:36:44    
2       smith           1         79        2016-04-13 14:25:57
3       phil            1         76        2016-04-18 18:06:21
4       leo             1         76        2016-04-18 15:51:41
5       craig           1         79        2016-04-20 10:44:17
...
```

table 2

```
p_id       p_name                         
75         test1             
76         test2             
77         test3             
78         test4             
79         test5             
...
```

table 3

```
id        c_id                         
1         1             
2         1             
3         3             
4         4             
5         4
```

I need the result:

```
period        p_id    p_name   total_count  active_count cance_count no_of_occur          
2016-04-13    79      test5    2            2            0           2
2016-04-18    76      test2    2            2            0           2
2016-04-20    79      test5    1            1            0           1
...
```

For code that I wrote quert but it gives me wrong count

```
SELECT 
   DATE(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 19800 SECOND)) AS period, table1.p_id, 
   MIN(mdcpev.value) AS product_name,
   COUNT(table1.c_id) AS total_count,
   SUM(status = 1) AS active_count,
   SUM(status = 2) AS cancel_count,
   COUNT(table3.id) AS no_of_occur,
     FROM table1
         INNER JOIN table2 AS mdcpev ON mdcpev.p_id = p_id
         LEFT JOIN table3 AS mdspo ON mdspo.c_id = tabe1.c_id
         GROUP BY DATE(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 19800 SECOND)),p_id
```

---

**EDIT**

my current query result is

```
   period        p_id    p_name   total_count  active_count cance_count no_of_occur          
    2016-04-13    79      test5    3            3            0           3
    2016-04-18    76      test2    3            3            0           2
    2016-04-20    79      test5    1            1            0           1
```

Here I got `active_count` 3 which is wrong it should be 2 and `no_of_occur`should be 2 and currently it display 3
Can anyone guide me to the what's wrong in this query ?

Thank you

Comment: what you want to count please be specific ??

Comment: And provide the output of your current query as well

Comment: Please check the output @Shadow

Comment: count should be no of c_id occur for particular day @WasiqMuhammad

Comment: @KeyurShah, Can you please make a fiddle?? It will be better for us.

Comment: you count `COUNT(table3.id)` so it count result shows 3. try with COUNT(table3.c_id)

Comment: Still no luck.... @FrayneKonok

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109758/discussion-between-keyur-shah-and-frayne-konok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, it will work.

```
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(table1.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d'),
        table1.p_id,
        table2.p_name,
        COUNT(table1.c_id) AS total_count,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN table1.c_id ELSE NULL end) AS active_count,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN table1.c_id ELSE NULL end) AS cancel_count,
        COUNT(table3.id) AS no_of_occur
           FROM table1
           JOIN table2
           on table2.p_id=table1.p_id
           JOIN table3
           ON table3.c_id=table1.c_id
           Group by DATE_FORMAT(table1.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d'),table1.p_id
```

**Output:**
I took dumy data as it from question and tried in my system..

[image]

Comment: No it's not working,,it also give me the same result

Comment: I modified query, remove distinct now check because without distinct i'm getting correct output, i checked in my system

Comment: then you have to debug itself or it can be better if you will create sqlfiddle.

Comment: https://www.db4free.net/phpMyAdmin/db_sql.php?db=test_keyur&token=17cf668a99add724881baa95ff12b3f2

Comment: Open this link enter user name keyur070 and password 123456

Comment: actualy query is too long append my query with single messages

Comment: SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 19800 SECOND)) AS period, md_subscribenow_product_subscribers.store_id, md_subscribenow_product_subscribers.product_id, MIN(mdcpev.value) AS product_name,COUNT(md_subscribenow_product_subscribers.subscription_id) AS subscriber_count, SUM(subscription_status = 1) AS active_subscriber, SUM(subscription_status = 2) AS pause_subscriber, SUM(subscription_status = 4) AS cancel_subscriber,

Comment: COUNT(mdspo.occurrence_id) AS no_of_occurrence, mdspo.occurrence_date FROM md_subscribenow_product_subscribers INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS mdcpev ON mdcpev.entity_id = product_id and mdcpev.attribute_id=70 LEFT JOIN md_subscribenow_product_occurrence AS mdspo ON mdspo.subscription_id = md_subscribenow_product_subscribers.subscription_id GROUP BY DATE(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 19800 SECOND)), store_id, product_id HAVING (subscriber_count > 0)

Answer (score 1):

Tha cause of the difference is the join with table3, since you have 1 and 4 twice in the c_id column and these will duplicate the records.

I would change the counts as follows:

```
COUNT(distinct table1.c_id) AS total_count,
Count(distinct case when status = 1 then table1.c_id else null end) AS active_count,
Count(distinct case when status = 2 then table1.c_id else null end) AS cancel_count,
COUNT(distinct table3.id) AS no_of_occur,
```

The distinct within the count ensures that only distinct values are counted. However, you will still have an issue with no_of_occur. If that is based on table3.id, then you will still get 3 for p_id 79 in the 1st record because the 1st record in table1 relates to 2 records in table3 and the second record in table1 relates to a 3rd record in table3. So, I believe your expectations are either incorrect or your no_of_occur calculation should not be tied to table3 at all. But in this case you do not even need table3 in the query. This is sg only you can answer.

Comment: by using distinct active_count get the wrong count, as you know if i have 3 id with status 1 then it displayonly 1,but i need 3 active_count

Comment: by using COUNT(distinct table1.c_id) i got the correct total_count . +1 from me but now I am getting wrong status count(active_count and cancel_count)

Comment: "but i need 3 active_count" vs in the question for the 1st record you have 2 in the active_count in the expected results column. Do you want 2 or 3 there? To me 2 is the obvious answer, not 3.

Comment: I want active_count as 2 not 3 as you can see my output

Comment: I have active_count and cancel_count as wrong result

Comment: The `Count(distinct case when status = 1 then table1.c_id else null end) AS active_count` should yield 2 as an output. Are you sure you have  table1.c_id in the case expression? Piyush also suggested this solution, so I'm quite convinced that the expression I suggested is the right one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109779/discussion-between-keyur-shah-and-shadow).

Comment: Chat is blocked here. But you should provide clear feedback on what goes wrong when you try to run our queries, do not simply say that it's wrong.

Comment: https://www.db4free.net/phpMyAdmin/db_sql.php?db=test_keyur&token=17cf668a99add724881baa95ff12b3f2

Comment: Open this link enter user name keyur070 and password 123456

Comment: actualy query is too long append my query with single messages

Comment: SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(`created_at`, INTERVAL 19800 SECOND)) AS `period`, `md_subscribenow_product_subscribers`.`store_id`, `md_subscribenow_product_subscribers`.`product_id`, MIN(mdcpev.value) AS `product_name`,COUNT(md_subscribenow_product_subscribers.subscription_id) AS `subscriber_count`, SUM(subscription_status = 1) AS `active_subscriber`, SUM(subscription_status = 2) AS `pause_subscriber`, SUM(subscription_status = 4) AS `cancel_subscriber`,

Comment: COUNT(mdspo.occurrence_id) AS `no_of_occurrence`, `mdspo`.`occurrence_date` FROM `md_subscribenow_product_subscribers` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `mdcpev` ON mdcpev.entity_id = product_id and mdcpev.attribute_id=70 LEFT JOIN `md_subscribenow_product_occurrence` AS `mdspo` ON mdspo.subscription_id = md_subscribenow_product_subscribers.subscription_id GROUP BY DATE(DATE_ADD(`created_at`, INTERVAL 19800 SECOND)), `store_id`, `product_id` HAVING (subscriber_count > 0)

Comment: You should use www.sqlfiddle.com. My browser cannot get past the login page pof db4free, it is waiting for a response from the server for over 5 mins now.

Answer (score 1):

`SUM(status = 1) AS active_count`, this always return true(1) for all condition. So you getting wrong output.

I hope this query will work.Please check.

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(table1.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d'),
    table1.p_id,
    table2.p_name,
    COUNT(table1.c_id) AS total_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status= 1 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS active_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status= 2 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS cancel_count,
    COUNT(table3.id) AS no_of_occur
       FROM table1
       JOIN table2
       on table2.p_id=table1.p_id
       JOIN table3
       ON table3.c_id=table1.c_id
       Group by DATE_FORMAT(table1.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d'),table1.p_id
```

Comment: still not get the actual result